# Check constraint on a pair of columns

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, check-constraints

I have a table with this structure:

```
create table licence_report
(
    id                          bigint         default nextval('licence_report_id_seq'::regclass) not null,
    created                     timestamp                                                         not null,
    last_modified               timestamp,
    licence_number              varchar(255)                                                      not null,
    state                       varchar(10)                                                           licence_type                varchar(255),
    constraint licence_report_pkey
        primary key (id, created)
)
    partition by RANGE (created);
```

I need to ensure that there is only one licence number in the state `NEW`, how do I add a constraint like this?

I tried the below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION offroad.check_new_reports_by_licence(licence_number_check varchar)
    RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$BODY$
    SELECT EXISTS(SELECT id
  FROM   licence_report
  WHERE  licence_number = licence_number_check
  AND    state = 'NEW');
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
    COST 100;

ALTER TABLE licence_report ADD CONSTRAINT const_check_existing_new_reports_by_licence CHECK (check_new_reports_by_licence(licence_number) = FALSE);
```

I get the following error:

```
[23514] ERROR: check constraint "const_check_existing_new_reports_by_licence" is violated by some row
```

But the output of this query is 0 rows:

```
SELECT licence_number
FROM licence_report
WHERE state = 'NEW'
GROUP BY licence_number
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: You want one licence with state NEW in the whole table?

Comment: Then you only need a unique partial index: `create unique index x on licence_report (state) where (state = 'NEW');` See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6e750e4cdf07fb3406fb056f176890a0

Comment: or `create unique index  y on licence_report (licence_plate) where (state = 'NEW');` if you need one row with NEW per licence_plate.

Comment: The problem is, its partitioned and needs created, hence unique wont work

Comment: Indeed, partiotioning imposes this limitation.